# command output redirection using '-< <( ... )'

Tags: bash, redirect, syntax

I needed to extract a shasum. This works, but can anyone explain why?

```
sed 's/^.*= //' -< <(openssl dgst -sha256 filename)
```

I'm familiar with the `$( )` construct, but can't find docs for `<( )`, coupled with `-<`, which I assume is redirecting to the `sed` STDIN.

I know there are easier ways, but this construct eludes me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The

```
<(openssl dgst -sha256 filename)
```

construct is a *process substitution*. It creates a file (or FIFO) behind the scenes and passes its name back to the command sequence.

```
<
```

is a regular file redirection, redirecting the contents of the behind-the-scenes file to `stdin` and

```
-
```

is a placeholder recognized by `sed` to indicate that its input is coming from `stdin`.

Since `sed` is perfectly capable of reading from files, the `-<` seems unnecessary in this context;

```
sed 's/^.*= //' <(openssl dgst -sha256 filename)
```

should work just as well.

Comment: or just `openssl ... | sed '...'`

Answer (score 9):

The `<( COMMAND )` Bash construct is called **process substitution**.

It evaluates the `COMMAND` inside and redirects its output to a FIFO, a named pipe that gets a virtual file descriptor inside `/dev/fd` assigned. It acts like a temporary file that contains the output of the evaluated command.

---

The `<` Bash construct is called **input redirection**.

It takes a file descriptor on the right side and redirects its content to the STDIN (standard input) of the command on the left side.

---

The `-` is not a Bash construct but an **argument for `sed`** that specifies its input file. The special value `-` means to **read from STDIN** (which is also `sed`'s default, so it could be omitted).

---

```
sed 's/^.*= //' - < <(openssl dgst -sha256 filename)
```

This line first runs `openssl dgst -sha256 filename` and caches its output in a FIFO. The file descriptor representing this named pipe is treated as input file that gets redirected to the STDIN of `sed 's/^.*= //' -`. This `sed` command reads from STDIN and removes every character before a "=" symbol followed by a space.